# Media queries in .jsp file are ignored on all mobile devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, media-queries

My shopping cart service allows custom css, but renders it in a .jsp file.

On a desktop the media queries work fine; however, they are ignored on all mobile devices.

How do I get them to work on mobiles?

Comment: add viewport meta <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Adding <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"> worked, so CoderHawk you are right it is a duplicate. Sorry I did try to find the answer before I posted.

Comment: don't be, it happens :)